# Hilbert transform of audio file

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I am working on acoustic signal processing, currently i am facing issues in getting Hilbert transform of an audio file.
I started with windowing the data and then used Hilbert transform of each window. below is my code:

```
import pylab
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.signal as signal
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10)
def goetrzel(data, target_frequency):
        s_prev = 0
        s_prev2 = 0
        normalized_frequency = 2.0 * np.pi * target_frequency / len(data)
        coeff = 2.0 * np.cos(normalized_frequency)
        for sample in data:
                s = sample + coeff * s_prev - s_prev2
                s_prev2 = s_prev
                s_prev = s
                power = s_prev2 * s_prev2 + s_prev * s_prev - coeff * s_prev * s_prev2
        return power

def sliding_window(data, length, skip=None):
        if skip is None:
                skip = length
        n = len(data)
        for i in range(0, n - int(length), int(skip)):
                yield data[i:i+length]
def hilbert(data):
    for sample in data:
        analytic_sig= hilbert(data)
        amplitude_env = np.abs(analytic_signal)
    return analytic_sig , amplitude_env

detect_frequency = 485.0

num=44100
rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('Downloads/ShortWAV.wav')

window_length = 400#2 * detect_frequency # How should I pick this?
window_skip = window_length # How should I pick this?

power = [goetrzel(window, detect_frequency) for window in sliding_window(data, window_length, window_skip)]
analytic_sig, amplitude_env =  [hilbert(window) for window in sliding_window(data, window_length, window_skip)]
pylab.figure()
pylab.plot(power)
pylab.show()
```

I am new python developer. the program is giving the error: Maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet below is your problem: you are calling the hilbert function within itself and since you have a lot of data points that causes the recursion limit being hit.

```
def hilbert(data):
    for sample in data:
        analytic_sig= hilbert(data)
```

You were probably trying to call the scipy `hilbert` function; I suggest changing the code to:

```
        analytic_sig = scipy.signal.hilbert(data)
```

You need to import the right module too; add to the top:

```
import scipy.signal
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already imported `scipy.signal` as signal, just change the code to:

```
analytic_sig = signal.hilbert(data)
```

[small modification to the answer by Cyb3rFly3r]